# Javascript + Run a function for X seconds

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to run my function within 5 seconds in `Javascript`?

For example if I have `Function A` and `Function B`. I want to run `Function A` for 5 seconds, just after it, it will run `Function B`.

- IF `Function A` only takes 1 second to finish the process, then it only need to wait another 4 seconds.
- But if `Function A` takes 3 seconds to finish, then it would need another 2 seconds to wait, before processing `Function B`
- IF `Function A` takes more than 5 seconds, then B needs to wait until A finish its job, until it can start its job. (edited)

Right now, im using Sleep Function that I found not long time ago

```
function wait(ms){
   var start = new Date().getTime();
   var end = start;
   while(end < start + ms) {
     end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}

wait(5000);
```

But with this code, it will need to wait for 5 seconds no matter how much time `Function A` needs to finish its process.

**EDIT**

`Function A` does an `AJAX POST` call. which makes it takes different time to finish its job.

This question is different from [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep) because :

1. this is going to be used in IE which doesn't support promise (as I read)
2. If I use settimeout, and A takes longer than 5 seconds, then B will fire it function first without waiting A to finish.

Comment: Don't you mean function a takes 7 seconds?

Comment: Is FunctionA performing asynchronous work? Or does it take 1 second for other reasons?

Comment: setTimeout, setInterval, $evalAsync, $applyAsync, web workers can do the job

Comment: A combination of setTimeout() and a promise() should do.

Comment: @casraf @Juhana `Function A` is Ajax `POST` call, which makes it finish the job in different time, depends on the process.

Comment: P.S., there are polyfills to implement missing features in missing browsers - newer IE don't need this usually, but for Promises+old IE, you can find a promise polyfill online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see these easiest approaches to this:

1. If `Function A` is asynchronous (e.g. sending an AJAX request and waiting for reply), simply use `setTimeout`, as the request will be done in the background and not freeze the main process. So `funcA()` will be immediately done running on the UI thread, then the next expression will immediately take place, (which waits for 5 seconds), then the callback from the AJAX response will be called whenever it's done fetching the response.

   ```
   funcA();
   setTimeout(funcB, 5000);
   ```
2. If `Function A` takes up to 5 seconds for other reasons, and you need the wait to be more dynamic, you could probably time it and subtract:

   ```
   var startTime = new Date().getTime(), endTime;
   funcA();
   endTime = new Date().getTime();
   setTimeout(funcB, 5000 - (endTime - startTime));
   ```
3. If `Function A` might take longer than 5 seconds, and `Function B` needs to wait for it, I suggest something similar to this:

   ```
   function funcA() {
     var startTime = new Date().getTime(), endTime;
     // ... code ...
     $.post(..., {
       ...,
       // when done/resolved the AJAX request ->
       success: function(response) {
         endTime = new Date().getTime();
         setTimeout(funcB, 5000 - (startTime - endTime));
       }
     });
   }
   ```

Comment: What if `funcA` takes 5001(or more) milliseconds to finish?
`waitTime = 5000 - (endTime - startTime); if(waitTime < 0) { waitTime = 0; }`

Comment: @aifrim Not necessary, because a negative timeout is automatically converted to the minimum.

Comment: what would happen if I use the first approach, but then FunctionA takes more than 5 seconds to finish. Would Func B do its job first without waiting the reply from FunctionA?

Comment: Yes, it will. If you really wanna get that deep into it, you can use some sort of condition that reflects if the task has been done, and try again every few milliseconds until that response is correct.

Comment: Though honestly, why don't you just use a promise and wait for the first response to finish? Why specifically 5 seconds?

Comment: @mark it would run after A finishes + 5 seconds. Because A does async stuff.

Comment: @alfrim no, if it performs async stuff, it literally will not wait for it to finish before proceeding with the task.

Comment: @casraf because im showing a real time data project. The project will show the last 5 seconds of data. Then after 5 seconds, it will keep updating the data. So Function B needs to be done right 5 seconds after A to make it looked smoothly. But if A takes longer than 5 seconds, then B still need to wait A, else the 'updated data' will be shown before the 'first data'

Comment: Check my update - 3rd bullet - should be what you need more or less